# UI testing in android using uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, testing

I followed the steps of Ui testing for the application from developers link

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

for java test project i added android-19 jar files of android.jar and uiautomator.jar
now i getting error when i use command

```
android create uitest-project -n LoginTest -t 1 -p D:\workspace_Project
```

Error: UI test projects can only target API 16 and above.

thanks.